# Preprocessor variables are not available on websocket request

Tags: jmeter

I'm adding a variable on a BeanShell Preprocessor:
vars.put("var",value).
I use it on a WebSocket request:
${var}.
When I send the request, the request body contains '${var}' instead of the value itself.

I tried to use also JSR223 Preprocessor.
I tried to put on the request '${_V(value)' and put it as property but nothing is working

Comment: From where are you initializing value?

Comment: from the preprocessor

Comment: If you are extracting value from Pre Processor, use statement like Beanshell PreProcessor: vars.put("var", vars.get("value")); Then you can use ${var}

Comment: Can you show us how your JMeter script structure looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JSR223 Sampler, and this is where you build your logic to initialize the value of your variable. Your variable will be looking like `vars.put("var",value);`

[image]

And after that you can reference the variable from different places in your script like `${var)`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I copied the code to JSR223 and now it's working

Comment: Cool! Please mark my answer as a solution for your issue!

Answer (score 0):

For your issue use statement like:

```
vars.put("var", vars.get("value")); //Then you can use ${var} elsewhere

Always use a Debug Sampler with View Results Tree for debugging.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ${var}, not ${value}. (I fixed the question).
Still waiting for answers please